# Reactjs : Unable to add update textfield in customBodyRender

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material-ui `TextField` value is not updated.
Example of expected working scenario and non working scenario below.

**[WORKING SCENARIO](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ssfzk?file=/demo.js:0-3620)** is here:

To replicate issue in working example, just comment this `setData(event.target.value);`

```js
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState("Change Me");
    const handleInput = (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();
       setData(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
     // Here value reflects in the textField as I am able to setData
      <TextField 
        id="standard-basic" 
        value={data} 
        onChange={handleInput} 
      />
    );
}
```

**THE FAILED SCENARIO**
Here, i have local `variable` instead of global like data above

```js
class DummyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { newVal : ''};
    this.onChangeText = this.onChangeText.bind(this);
  }

  return (
     options: {
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta) => (
          <TextField
            // local variable, below
            value={value === null || value === 'null' ? '' : value}
            onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
            onKeyUp={(event) => {
              if (event.ctrlKey && event.key== 'Enter')
                  this.onChangeText(event, meta, meta.rowData)
            }}
          />
        )
     }
  )
  
  onChangeText = (event, tableMeta, row) => {
    event.persist();
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(event.target.value);
    this.setState({ newRadar : event.target.value }, () => {
       alert(this.state.newValue);
    });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     this.setState({ newVal : event.target.value })
  }
// ...other
```

Comment: Your code with issues seems syntactically incorrect. Within the body of the class you have a `return` statement. That doesn't belong there, what are you expecting to happen with a return statement there? Do you mean for that to be your `render` function?

Comment: I'll also add a point of clarification: `data` in your first snippet is not global. It is local to any individual rendering of your `BasicTextFields` component. If all you are trying to do is add support for your `ctrl+Enter` keyup to do something special, you may be better off starting with that as your example than moving to the class component. It will likely be easier to read/maintain